# Why can docker images not be merged?

Tags: docker

I have learned that [docker images cannot be merged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711924/merge-two-docker-images).  But why not?  It would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is an app container and you should be running one process per container. So, it makes sense to split images into specific roles. For example, container image for `nginx`, container image for `mongo` etc. Having said that you can bake multiple images content into one but that is like constructing a whole OS container which doesn't seem to align with docker app containers philosophy.

Comment: But in many cases one process requires multiple images, for example if I want to combine the OpenFace with TensorFlow I need both the bamos/openface and nvidia/cuda containers.

Comment: I feel merging will be interesting/complex to implement given base image for the two images can differ. Also, what sort of dependencies these two components have? if one of them is a helper for proess/service I will just install it rather than thinking about merging docker images.