# Docker - accidently commited without specifying an image, generating a new one. How to update the old image instead?

Tags: docker

After doing extensive work on a very large image I accidently ran `docker commit CONTAINER_ID` instead of `docker commit CONTAINER_ID IMAGE`. My intention was to update the old image with the new work, but now I have two very large images instead:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                 TAG             IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
<none>                     <none>          78aebb8ed5af   35 minutes ago   88.6GB
my-ubuntu                  latest          a153f4458b1a   14 hours ago     28.8GB
```

How can I fix this, that is, have only a single image `my-ubuntu` with the changes currently present only in the new image?

I tried `docker image rm my-ubuntu` to keep only the new image which is more up to date, but this gives:

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete my-ubuntu (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
```

I suppose that's because the new image was built from `my-ubuntu`, but... I do not wish to delete the new image and re-do all the work and commit again. Is there any way this can be avoided?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38119847/2032568) suggests deleting dangling images, but `docker images --filter "dangling=true"` returns precisely the new image which I do not want to delete. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713151/2032568) suggests creating a docker file from both images and generating a new image, but the output of that command for the new image is the same as for `my-ubuntu` except a new sha256 entry with the work done on the new image, so should I just create a dockerfile from it and then an imagem from the dockerfile? I'm new to docker and unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Running `docker tag 78aebb8ed5af my-ubuntu` did the job.